# SSIS Package that removes or ignores multiple rows in flat file

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I'm learning how to develop SSIS packages for ETL systems this week. One of my first objectives is to discover different ways to import flat files into a database. As this is pretty straight forward for the most part, I've been playing around with different flat files that contain a variety of data.

One issue I ran into today was with a Excel document that contained data in the first row, the header information in the second row and foot information in the last couple of rows. What I want to import into the database is the header and all the rows leading up to the footer. I do not want the first row and I do not want the footer.

My current solution is to create a Data Flow task in Advance Settings and OpenRowSet with "Sheet1$A2:I20000". This allows me to open the sheet I want, select the second row (where my header resides) and then select all other rows that are between A2 and I20000.

[image]

This solution also allows me to read the header information (which I want) and all the rows that follow for importation. Unfortunately, this also selects the footer rows and doesn't seem optimize for good performance as the package has to scan a massive range of rows regardless if there is data in those rows or not.

The screenshot below contains the Excel sheet that I'm trying to import based on the MS SQL sample database. The rows I want to remove or ignore are circles with the red box. Everything else not circled is what I want to import.

[image]

Any thoughts on how I can ignore the first row, read the second row for my header information, read the rows that follow the header for my data set and then ignore the last couple of rows that I'm deeming as the footer?

**Addition Information About This File**

- The first row will never change.
- The header row will never change.
- The data set after the header will change values, not data types.
- The first column of footer will never change.
- The second column of footer will change values, not data types.
- The rest of the footer columns will never change.

Comment: Will the rows you want to send to your OLE DB destination always start on row 2? Why do you want to capture the header row? Are you storing the header row data in the OLE DB destination as well? The rows you want to ignore, will they always have SUM Total in the first column?

Comment: I want to capture the header row to ensure it never changes. I may just put that header into a new table by itself for validation purposes. I guess for this example, I don't really need it. And yes to the last question. The SUM TOTALS will always be at the end and in the first column of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution to my own question.

I used the Conditional Split as shown in my diagram to filter out the rows I didn't need. For example, I put a condition that checks if the first column of data (member_no) was < (less than) a number. If TRUE, it goes to my OLE DB. If False, it goes nowhere. This prevented the "SUM TOTAL" from being passed to the database.

I also edited my start range with 'Sheet1$A2:I' as opposed to 'Sheet1$A2:I20000'. That way the package scans until there is no records to scan and stops (I assume).